# Eregi() Deprecated php help?

Tags: php, deprecated

I am recieving the error:

```
Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\registration\class.register.php on line 75
```

with my code::

```
if(empty($this->email) || !eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$',$this->email))
```

What alternative should I use and how can I implement it????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `ereg` family functions [have been deprecated](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html), you need to use `preg` family functions instead. In your case, you should use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

That piece of code is equivalent to:

```
if(empty($this->email) || 
    !preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$~i',
    $this->email))
```

It can also be compacted to:

```
if(empty($this->email) || !preg_match('~^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$~i',
    $this->email))
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Sarfraz said `ereg_*` functions are deprecated and you should use `preg_*` instead. However in this case you shouldn't use regular expressions at all. There is function called [`filter_var()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) that allows you to validate some popular data formats (emails, URLs etc.)

```
if (empty($this->email) || false == filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Empty or not valid email
}
```